# SFORZANDO GUI in UBUNTU 23.04 does not open

Tags: audio-recording

I downloaded win64 version of Sforzando. installed the ZIP file with latest WINE Version . But when I want to open Sforzando it stops, telling me, cannot open GUI . DirektD2 not installed.
Any chance to solve this problem!

btw.: as being born in 1953 I did not grow up with computers!
New to Linux ,
new to ARDOUR!

If you can help, please keep that in mind! :-))

THX!

Tried to find hints via search, could not find any!
Only found messages, that some of you succeeded installing Sforzando on Linux